# jQuery Dropdown Menu with ID's Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Please, have a look at http://www.projects.iasad.me/services.html

**Problem:** When I try to visit Our Services drop-down menu from another page (i.e Home, About, contact etc) the drop down doesn't work properly. Example: Suppose I want to visit *Corporate Advisory* of *Our Services* Submenu from Home page but it will go to *Fixed Income Trading* Submenu of *Our Services* instead. Why that happens? Here are the codes:

```js
$(function(){

      $(".dropdown-menu .menu2").click(function(){
       
         $("#corporate-advisory").show();
         $("#get-in-touch").css({
             'margin-top':'20%'
         });
         $("#fixed-income-trading").hide();
         $("#investment-management").hide();
     });  
    
     $(".dropdown-menu .menu3").click(function(){
           
         $("#investment-management").show();
         $("#get-in-touch").css({
             'margin-top':'20%'
         });
             
         $("#fixed-income-trading").hide();
         $("#corporate-advisory").hide();
     });  
  
     $(".dropdown-menu .menu1").click(function(){

         $("#fixed-income-trading").show();
         $("#corporate-advisory").hide();
         $("#investment-management").hide();
     }); 
    
});
```

Please help me.
Regards.

Comment: I cant reproduce the problem, and if it really is "urgent!" then I would advise you to do and hire someone on another page.

Answer (score 1):

If this jQuery code is only included on the  services page, the click events will only be triggered while already on that page; hence why you are always directed to the 'fixed income trading' section.

as for the browser scrolling;

```html
<li><a  class="menu1 menu" href="services.html#fixed-income-trading">Fixed income</a></li>
```

The #fixed-income-trading part of the link will move the browser to a part of the page with the id 'fixed-income-trading'.

However, this is not needed if you are hiding the unwanted parts with jQuery?

Comment: Hi,I wrote the jQuery codes into a file called scripts.js and i linked the file to all the pages. In the services.html page there have three sections,I need to show only one section when user click the drop down option. That's why i have to hide tow section and show one section per click.By default Fixed Income Trading section is visible.

Comment: I would sugest using a querystring to pass the name of the section you are trying to view, e.g. 
href="services.html?section=FA"
or 
href="services.html?section=CA"


Then, when the services page loads, you can detect the query string, and hide/show the related sections.

https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-querystring-with-native-javascript/

Comment: Okay, where should I put the query string?In jQuery codes or dropdown menu? Please give me a hints.

Comment: In the link 
<li><a  class="menu1 menu" href="services.html?section=FI">Fixed income</a></li>

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the reason to use a query string. My problem is my codes are fine when I visit from services.html to the drop-down menu. But when I try to visit the drop-down menu link from another page instead of services.html it doesn't work.I just want to know why it's happening?